# Force macbook to sleep when lid closed and external monitor connected in Lion

Tags: macos, display, sleep-wake

I know you have heard this before, but is there any app/hack that makes the computer behave like Snow Leopard when closing the lid?

I don't want to hear about this being a duplicate question, as I want a solution not an explanation.

Only post here if you have a solution that makes the macbook behave like in Snow Leopard when closing the lid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't closing the lid sleep my MacBook Pro with external monitor attached after upgrading to Lion?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/why-wont-closing-the-lid-sleep-my-macbook-pro-with-external-monitor-attached-aft)

Comment: Not a solution, but remember you can always use ⌥⌘⏏ to sleep the computer.

Comment: Not even realized this as I usually close the lid and switch off immediately the external monitor... :-/

Comment: @LudoMC have had my macbook running in the night three times now, because I forgot to remove the cable to the external monitor, as I also switch my monitor off immediately :S

Comment: @Tyilo Just ran an uptime command which shows mine is up for more than 3 days now! Hopefully I now know I have to manually put him at sleep.

Comment: Please clarify precisely what behaviour you want, that closing the lid always triggers sleep?

Comment: @dan8394 external monitor connected; close lid; mac sleeps

Comment: There're a lot of people who want this, and there seems to be no solution. Perhaps filing a radar could help it?

Comment: @Akku Filing a radar? What is this?

Comment: It's a support system they use at Apple where you can file bugs and other inconveniences. I never did this myself, therefore I suggested it here in hope that someone else would do it :-)

Comment: @Akku wow great: http://cl.ly/984A

Comment: :-) Hope they'll fix this, it really annoys me.

Comment: Just a word of warning - I used my MacBook Pro with the lid closed and an external monitor for a few months - but now the fans make a decidely 'used' noise - I blame the fact that the fans were overworked as the MacBook fans vent through the gap between the display and the keyboard, and this is blocked with the lid closed.

Comment: @Akku, in addition to radar-filing, there's their simple feedback page: http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked in 10.7 and 10.8 with my MacBook Air:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=iog=0x0
```

After restarting, it should restore the pre-10.7 behavior:

- Closing the lid puts a laptop to sleep even when it is connected to an external display
- If you then wake the laptop up and open the lid, the internal display doesn't turn on

To undo it, run `sudo nvram -d boot-args` or hold ⌥⌘PR on startup.

Comment: This worked for me on a 10.9.4 Macbook Air! BUT... Is there a way to have the internal display turn on when you wake on the laptop?

Comment: This worked for my MBP running Mavericks, but only if I disconnected the power and monitor before running the command, rebooting the Mac, and then reconnecting the power and monitor. Not sure if it was the rebooting, the disconnecting, or both.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue too, and came up with this script that monitors your lid state and puts the machine to sleep when lid is closed: https://github.com/pirj/noclamshell

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of OS X, you would go to ~/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration to find a file called com.apple.PowerManagement.plist. In that file you would find ways to tweak things like the old "clamshell" mode. I have not looked in Lion yet to see if this still exists, but if the file is still there, you may want to take a look at what it allows you to control. Hope this helps.

Comment: There is the option for "Wake On Clamshell Open", but not "Sleep On Clamshell Close", or something similiar. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/44Zrr.png

Comment: @Christian_Correa, btw this is in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration, not ~/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will still work with Lion, but on SL I use [InsomniaX](http://semaja2.net/insomniaxinfo) when I want to close the lid and prevent my mbp from sleeping. Check out the following links for similar programs:

http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22211/insomniax

http://alternativeto.net/software/insomniax/

Comment: I don't want to prevent the Mac from sleeping. I want it to sleep when I close the lid!

Comment: @tyilo: oops, totally read that backwards :)

Comment: left my answer up in case that app helps someone with the opposite problem...

Answer (score 0):

I made a LaunchAgent which does this.
The source code can be downloaded here: https://github.com/Tyilo/Lid-sleep

Comment: Does it work in Yosemite? How would I use this LaunchAgent? Thank you.