# Lion changes the sleep behavior when closing the lid of a MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

In Snow Leopard, whenever you close the lid of a MacBook, it puts it into sleep mode. Simple as that.

In Lion, it only puts it into sleep mode if it's running on it's battery. If it's plugged in it stays awake.

Does anybody know how I can get MacBook to start sleeping when I close the lid, regardless of charging state again?

Comment: My early-2011 MBP 15" running Lion does go to sleep when I close the lid, whether it's on power or battery.  perhaps you can supply more details of your scenario so that folks can help figure out why it's not working for you?

Comment: That's a great question, but I would consider editing the title before a moderator does it for you :)  It's funny, but it does't help people search for similar problems ;)

Comment: @David I have a late 2010 13" MacBook Pro. Did you buy yours with Lion on it?

Comment: No, my MBP was upgraded from Snow Leopard.

Comment: @David Weird. I thought that might of been my problem, but I guess not. :\

Comment: My old black Macbook with a clean install of Lion goes to sleep when I close the lid.  It does not always go to sleep just sitting open, but I suspect this has to do with what apps are running at the time.

Comment: I figured out the problem! :D

Comment: Same question, but more answers over here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/why-wont-closing-the-lid-sleep-my-macbook-pro-with-external-monitor-attached-aft

Comment: @Alexander Different question, I have no external monitor.

Comment: @Tyler Ah, sorry, missed that subtle difference :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok guys, I figured it out.

I don't really know what is going on underneath, but it has something to do with having "Internet Sharing" enabled. Just disable it when you're not using it and your MacBook should now go into sleep mode when the lid is closed, even when it's plugged in.

Comment: In my case it was the `Screen Sharing` option which I had to turn off. It seems like you have to disable all options in `System Preferences -> Sharing`.

Comment: After playing around it seems to work now. **Turning it off and on seems to fix it**. However you have to wait a little longer until it goes to sleep (in case it is charging).

Answer (score 1):

When the lid is closed, the Mac would always begin to try to sleep, I should think. However, if there are external devices connected, these may wake/prevent the sleep; external display, USB devices, etc.

To confirm this, open Console.app and see the logs around the time of the lid closing. If something is preventing the sleep, it will be reported.