# How to disable clamshell mode behaviour? Force machine lock on lid close

Tags: sleep-wake, screen, macbook-pro

90% of the time I work with my macbook connected to a screen.

I want my macbook to go to preferably lock, but will settle for sleep, when I close it.

I don't care if it is doing anything, if I close the lid, I want the entire machine to lock/sleep.

This does not seem to be possible from what I can tell but I am hoping that you can prove me wrong.

Thanks for any suggestions that you can offer.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/why-wont-closing-the-lid-sleep-my-macbook-pro-with-external-monitor-attached-af?rq=1 quit old though .

Answer (score 2):

Sadly I don't think you can invoke this behavior and this is not the solution you are asking for, though as I imagine you are using a keyboard (apple?) you could always use the hotkeys to lock your laptop and screen.

- <kbd>Option</kbd>–<kbd>Command</kbd>–<kbd>Power</kbd> / <kbd>Option</kbd>–<kbd>Command</kbd>–<kbd>Media Eject</kbd>: Put Mac to
  sleep
- <kbd>Control</kbd>–<kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>Power</kbd> / <kbd>Control</kbd>–<kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>Media Eject</kbd> : Put
  display(s) to sleep

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236

Answer (score 0):

There’s not a reliable way to disable closed clamshell. Instead, I would use the key command to lock the screen before you close the lid and set screensaver to need a password immediately.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834 Closed Clamshell Functionality
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236 Mac Keyboard Shortcuts

Control-Command-Q: Immediately lock your screen

You can mess with sleep, but without the settings / lock it’s less secure.

Answer (score 0):

There is a script to do so: https://github.com/pirj/noclamshell

> **How does this work**
>
> It periodically checks if lid is closed and puts machine to sleep. Nothing fancy, it uses command line tools that come with OSX, specifically ioreg, which displays I/O registry and pmset to manipulate power management settings.

```
brew install pirj/noclamshell/noclamshell
brew services start noclamshell
```